# Getting "No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator."

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, my-site, self-service

I am getting "No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator." while enabling "Self-Service Site Creation"

User profile application has been created and associated with Web application.

"Use Self-Service Site Creation" has been enabled in "User Permissions"

I checked below link as well but no luck.
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2010-my-site-creation-error.html

Please suggest.

Comment: Try doing an IISRESET then test again. If this issue still exists, you need to check ULS log to find more information about this error.

Comment: Did you check whether User Profile service is started in Central Administration? If not, start it and do a IISRESET afterwards.

Comment: I did iisrest but no luck. in log getting :Application error when access /_admin/ConfigSSC.aspx, Error=No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.  System.InvalidOperationException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.